# How to separate authors on different lines in Quarto pdf

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto

I am preparing a Quarto pdf document and would like to specify the authors on separate lines beneath the unit to which they belong. When I knit my .qmd as an html, I get the desired output:

```r
---
title: "Untitled"
author: 
  - "**Analytics Unit**"
  - "John Smith"
  - "Jane Doe"
format: html
---
```

[image]

However, when I switch the format to pdf, the authors names are spread across a single line

```r
---
title: "Untitled"
author: 
  - "**Analytics Unit**"
  - "John Smith"
  - "Jane Doe"
format: pdf
---
```

[image]

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use latex package `authblk`

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author:
  - "**Analytics Unit**"
  - "John Smith"
  - "Jane Doe"
format: pdf
include-in-header:
  text: |
   \usepackage{authblk}
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

---

[image: Author name at different lines]

---

If author names seems a bit larger to you, use `auth-lg` package option, that is modify your YAML as,

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author:
  - "**Analytics Unit**"
  - "John Smith"
  - "Jane Doe"
format: pdf
include-in-header:
  text: |
   \usepackage[auth-lg]{authblk}
---
```

I would recommend to read the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/authblk.pdf), Especially section 4 and 5.